# Reading and analyzing rooms from text file

Tags: c, file, struct

My program crashes and I can't find where. I tried debugging with printf on almost every line, but I just can't find what's wrong. *I THINK* that it may be at the `readLine` function, but I'm just completely lost.

The input file that I'm using is

```
*HallStudyCellarKitchen*StudyHallGarden*CellarHall*KitchenHallGarden*GardenStudyKitchen
```

Which means that every '*' separates a new room and then it shows where doors in that room lead to.

Code of my program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 10
#define BMAX 100
struct room * rooms[MAX];
int rp; // room count


// struct room - name, array of up to 4 doors, number of doors
struct room {char * name; struct door * doors[4]; int dp;};
// struct door - name for the room it connects to, & a pointer to that room
struct door {char * name; struct room * room;};

struct door * newDoor(char * name){
    struct door * d; // pointer d to the address of door
    d = (struct door *) malloc(sizeof(struct door));
    d->name = name; // name of new door is name
    d->room = NULL; // NULL room pointer
    return d;

};

struct  room * newRoom(char * name){
    struct room * r; // pointer r to the address of room
    printf("New room is %s\n",name);
    r = (struct room *) malloc(sizeof(struct room));
    r->name = name; // name of new room is name
    r->dp = 0; // no doors
    return r;
};

showRoom(struct  room * r){
    int i;
    printf("room name: %s\n", r->name);
        for (i = 0; i < (r->dp); r++){
            printf("%d %s\n", i,r->doors[i]->name);
        }
}

showRooms(){
    int i;
      for (i = 0; i < rp; i++){
    showRoom(rooms[i]);
      }
}


char * readLine(FILE * fin){
  char buffer[BMAX];
  int i,j;
  char ch;
  char * l;
  i = 0;
  ch = getc(fin);
  if (ch == EOF)
    return NULL;
  while (ch!='\n' && i < (BMAX - 1)){
    buffer[i] = ch;
    i++;
    ch = getc(fin);
  }
  if (ch != '\n')
    while (ch != '\n')
      ch = getc(fin);
  buffer[i] = '\0';
  l = malloc((i+1) * sizeof(char));
  for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    l[j] = buffer[j];
    l[j] = '\0';

  return l;

}

readRooms(FILE * fin)
{  char * l;
   rp = 0;
    // printf("3"); fflush(stdout);
    while((l = readLine(fin)) != NULL)
    {  
         if(rp > MAX)
      {  
          printf("it's too many rooms\n");
         exit(0);
      }
      //printf("%s",l);
      rooms[rp] = newRoom(l);
      //l = readLine(fin);

      if (strncmp(l,"*")==0){
          //printf("2"); fflush(stdout);
          rp++;  

      }

         while(strncmp(l,"*")!=0) 
      {
          //printf("1"); fflush(stdout);
            if((rooms[rp] -> dp) > 4)
         {  printf("it's too many doors\n");
            exit(0);
         }
         rooms[rp] -> doors[rooms[rp] -> dp] = newDoor(l);
         rooms[rp] -> dp++;
         l = readLine(fin);

      }
      //rooms[rp] -> dp = 0;
      //rp++;
      //l = readLine(fin);
   }
}

connect()
{  int i,j,k;
   for(i = 0; i < rp; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < rooms[i]->dp; j++)
    {  for(k = 0; k < rp; k++)
        if(strcmp(rooms[k]->name,rooms[i]->doors[j]->name) == 0)
        {  rooms[i]->doors[j]->room = rooms[k];
           break;
        }
       if(k == rp)
       {  printf("can't find %s\n",rooms[i]->doors[j]->name);
          exit(0);
       }
    }
}

int main(int argc,char ** argv){
    FILE * fin;
    struct room * r; // current room
   // struct door * d;
   int d;

    if((fin=fopen(argv[1],"r"))==NULL)
   {  printf("cannot open %s\n",argv[1]);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   printf("11"); fflush(stdout);
     readRooms(fin);
     printf("22");
   fclose(fin);
   showRooms();
   connect();
   r = rooms[0];
   while(1)
   {  showRoom(r);
      printf("enter door number> ");
      scanf("%d",&d);
       if(d >= (r->dp))
       printf("bad door number\n");
      else
       r = r->doors[d]->room;
   }

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

What might be causing the crash, and how can I resolve it?

Comment: what output do you get when it crashes? It would help if you could point to the part of the code where it crashes. your printf should lead you somewhere?

Comment: This might be a great point in time to stop relying on printf to do your debugging and get some experience with an actual debugger.

Comment: `#include <string.h>` for `strcmp`

Comment: I really hope there is an `\n` somewhere in your input file.

Comment: @Ufonautas This code doesn't compile. Some of your functions don't have a return type.

Answer (score 0):

The readLine function does look a bit error prone:

```
char * readLine(FILE * fin){
    char buffer[BMAX];
    int i,j;
    char ch;
    char * l;
    i = 0;
    ch = getc(fin);
    if (ch == EOF)
        return NULL;
    while (ch!='\n' && i < (BMAX - 1)){
        buffer[i] = ch;
        i++;
        ch = getc(fin);
    }
    // The test on the next line is not necessary: it will be caught
    // by the first run of the following while loop.
    if (ch != '\n')
        while (ch != '\n')
            ch = getc(fin);
    buffer[i] = '\0';
    // Allocate a region of memory of (probably) i+1 bytes
    l = malloc((i+1) * sizeof(char));
    // j will range from zero to i, terminating when j = i+1
    for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        l[j] = buffer[j];
    // j now equals i+1 and l[j] is one beyond the size of the memory allocated at l.
    l[j] = '\0';

    return l;

}
```

Fix this by changing the condition on the loop

```
    // j will range from zero to i-1, terminating when j = i
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
        l[j] = buffer[j];
    // j now equals i and l[j] is the last element of the memory allocated at l.
    l[j] = '\0';
```

Notes:

1) You should always check the return value from `malloc`.

2) The actual size of memory allocated by `malloc` may be more than that requested, depending on the heap implementation, the processor architecture and the actual library function used.

Also, you should be nice and call `free` on every pointer that you have assigned using `malloc`.  The memory will be cleaned up eventually when the process terminates (if it's running in a fairly common OS), but it's good practice to do housekeeping, especially on those temporary buffers returned by `readLine`.

You may also want to take a look at the `if(rp > MAX)` line in `readRooms` and see if could cause an over run for the 11th room.

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect usage of `int strncmp(const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t n);` in 2 places.  Suggest replacing with `strcmp()`.

```
// if (strncmp(l,"*")==0)
if (strcmp(l,"*")==0)
```

If your compiler did not warning about this, either enable more warnings or get a new compiler.

Suspect off by 1

```
// if (rp > MAX)
if (rp >= MAX)

// if((rooms[rp] -> dp) > 4)
if ((rooms[rp] -> dp) >=  4)
```

---

Minor fixes to `readLine()` follow

```
char * readLine(FILE * fin){
  char buffer[BMAX];
  int i,j;

  // char ch;
  int ch;

  char * l;
  i = 0;
  ch = getc(fin);
  if (ch == EOF)
    return NULL;

  // while (ch!='\n' && i < (BMAX - 1)){
  while (ch!='\n' && ch!= EOF &&  i < (BMAX - 1)){

    buffer[i] = ch;
    i++;
    ch = getc(fin);
  }
  if (ch != '\n')

    // while (ch != '\n')
    while (ch != '\n' && ch!= EOF)

      ch = getc(fin);
  buffer[i] = '\0';

  // l = malloc((i+1) * sizeof(char));
  l = malloc(i+1);  // sizeof(char) is always 1
  if (l == NULL) Handle_OOM();

  for (j = 0; j <= i; j++)
    l[j] = buffer[j];
  l[j] = '\0';

  return l;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> What might be causing the crash, and how can I resolve it?

One possible (and the probable) cause of the crash is this loop in `readRooms()`:

```
         while(strncmp(l,"*")!=0) 
      {
          //printf("1"); fflush(stdout);
            if((rooms[rp] -> dp) > 4)
         {  printf("it's too many doors\n");
            exit(0);
         }
         rooms[rp] -> doors[rooms[rp] -> dp] = newDoor(l);
         rooms[rp] -> dp++;
         l = readLine(fin);

      }
```

The `l = readLine(fin)` at the end of the loop sets `l` to `NULL` when EOF is reached, and this null pointer is wrongly passed to `strncmp()` (also which is, as chux noted, missing the third argument).

Before you can resolve that, you must make up your mind about the input file format, that is to say whether the rooms go on one and the same line, as in your question - then you can't read a single room with `readLine()` in its current form - or the rooms go on separate lines.